# pass the intents to previous Activity in Android?

Tags: android

Buttons navigate to previous Activity but why does not pass intents to previous activity.

This is my code.

```
 btnSaveRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                /*
                finish();*/

               /* Intent i = new Intent(Record_Audio.this, AddPost.class);
                i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", newAudioFile);
                //setResult(8, i);
                //finish();//finishing activity
                startActivityForResult(i,8);
*/
                getIntent().putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", newAudioFile);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.back, R.anim.back_out);
            }
        });
```

And here is previous Activity code in onActivityResult

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
{
 if(requestCode==1010 && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
                {
                    String STRING_I_NEED=data.getStringExtra("STRING_I_NEED");
                    Log.e("","STRING_I_NEED = "+STRING_I_NEED);}

}
}
```

Comment: Where is your `data` defined? Can't you just create a new Intent and put your result, instead of `getIntent()` in your first code snippet?

Comment: I edited my post please see above . I put the whole code of onActivityResult.

Comment: where have you started the the activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
btnSaveRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", newAudioFile);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.back, R.anim.back_out);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass data back to previous activity using a new `Intent`.

Change

```
getIntent().putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", newAudioFile);
setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
```

to

```
Intent intent=new Intent();  
intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", newAudioFile);
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to pass the same result code for intent in previous activity like

FirstActivity:-
int requestCode = 2222;

Intent intent = new Intent(this,Classname.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode); 

SecondActivity:-
int requestCode = 2222;

btnSaveRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                /*
                finish();*/

               /* Intent i = new Intent(Record_Audio.this, AddPost.class);
                i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", newAudioFile);
                //setResult(8, i);
                //finish();//finishing activity
                startActivityForResult(i,8);
*/
                getIntent().putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", newAudioFile);
                setResult(requestCode, getIntent());
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.back, R.anim.back_out);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a Two activiies

On second Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i=new Intent();
    i.putExtra("msg", text);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
    finish();
    Log.i("","<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"+text );
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

on First Actvivty

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            String str = data.getStringExtra("msg");

            tv.setText(str);
             tv1=tv.getText().toString();
             tv2 = tv1;

            Log.d(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", "" + tv2);

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```